# How to reconstruct Bayer to RGB from Canon RAW data?

Tags: image, video, image-processing, graphics, matrix

I'm trying to reconstruct RGB from RAW Bayer data from a Canon DSLR but am having no luck. I've taken a peek at the dcraw.c source, but its lack of comments makes it a bit tough to get through. Anyway, I have debayering working but I need to then take this debayered data and get something that looks correct. My current code does something like this, in order:

1. Demosaic/debayer
2. Apply white balance multipliers (I'm using the following ones: 1.0, 2.045, 1.350. These work perfectly in Adobe Camera Raw as 5500K, 0 Tint.)
3. Multiply the result by the inverse of the camera's color matrix
4. Multiply the result by an XYZ to sRGB matrix fromm Bruce Lindbloom's site (the D50 sRGB one)
5. Set white/black point, I am using an input levels control for this
6. Adjust gamma

Some of what I've read says to apply the white balance and black point correction before the debayer. I've tried, but it's still broken.

Do these steps look correct? I'm trying to determine if the problem is 1.) my sequence of operations, or 2.) the actual math being used.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's still broken"? Broken in what way? Too bright? too dark? looks like it was pseudo-colored? Produces noise? What is the actual problem?

Answer (score 1):

The first step should be setting black and saturation point because you need to apply white balance looking after saturated pixels in order to avoid magenta highlights:
[image]

And before demosaicing, apply white balacing. See here (http://www.guillermoluijk.com/tutorial/dcraw/index_en.htm) how applying white balance before demosaicing introduce artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

After the first step (debayer) you should have a proper RGB image with right colors. Remaining steps are just cosmetics. So I'm guessing there's something wrong at step one.

One problem could be the Bayer pattern you're using to generate RGB image is different from the CFA pattern of the camera. Match sensor alignment in your code to that of the camera!